# Missing a constant on load.. how can i get around this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants, bundle, requirements, bundler

I just installed bundler for a rails 2.3.5 Spree project.

After doing so, I realized that I was getting this error when I went to `script/console` :

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing':NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Plugin::OpenID
```

**My Gemfile :**

```
gem 'ruby-openid', '2.1.8'
```

I ran `bundle install` with no errors.

**>> gem list -d ruby-openid**

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ruby-openid (2.1.8, 2.1.2)
Author: JanRain, Inc
Homepage: http://github.com/openid/ruby-openid
Installed at (2.1.8): /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
             (2.1.2): /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

**Full Backtrace**

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Rails::Plugin::OpenID (NameError)
    from /Users/macuser/Sites/test/spree/vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/init.rb:16:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `call'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `evaluate_method'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `send'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `send'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:631:in `prepare_dispatcher'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:185:in `process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from ./script/../config/../lib/spree/initializer.rb:90:in `run'
    from /Users/macuser/Sites/test/spree/config/environment.rb:26
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from script/server:3:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Any clues as to what to inspect now? Thanks ahead!

Comment: a full stacktrace might be more helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen mention of this before - I think it might have to do with require syntax in the Gemfile...

I just hacked a Gemfile together and threw in...

```
gem "ruby-openid", :require => 'openid'
```

Was able to fire up console in an admittedly scaled-down test environment...

Comment: Unbelievable! It worked! What does 'require' even do?? Amazing, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Per the bundler documentation - you're telling bundler to require a file that's different that the gem's name...meaning it loads openid.rb instead of ruby-openid.rb...